# Simultaneous Localization and Mapping(SLAM) simulation

Tags: artificial-intelligence, robotics

I am planning to do a project on Simultaneous Localization and Mapping(SLAM) using simulation since I am completely new to robotics I have no idea where to start and how to proceed.Please do help me to begin my work and I need some references for the tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to use [Robot Operating System (ROS)](http://www.ros.org). It has good development tools and the algorithms for SLAM and planning already available. You can start with [installing ROS](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation) followed by [ROS tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials).